# pythonの関数に配列を引数にしたときに、配列の中身で条件分岐を行う書き方について

Tags: python, python3

Python3.6を用いて、与えられた配列の中身によって出力を変えるような関数を作りたいと考えています。

```
input_data = [1,2,3]
def equ(x):
if xの各要素のそれぞれの値 > 2:
    return x+3
else:
    return x+1
```

equ(input_data)の期待される出力：[2,3,6]

このような関数を作成するためにはどのようにすればできるでしょうか？
もし、できないならばどのようにしたら効率よくコーディングできるでしょうか？

以上、よろしくお願い致します

Comment: > `xの中身` とは、 `リストxの要素数` `xの各要素のそれぞれの値` `xの総和、平均など` のうち、どれを指していますか？

Comment: 説明不十分で申し訳ございません．書き加えます
xの中身とは各要素のそれぞれの値を指しています．

Answer (score 2):

## 配列を受け取る構成の場合

配列の各要素をforで回すと良さそうです。

```
input_data = [1, 2, 3]


def equ(x):
    result = []
    for e in x:
        if e > 2:
            result.append(e + 3)
        else:
            result.append(e + 1)
    return result
print(equ(input_data))
```

## 配列の各要素を受け取る構成の場合

配列そのものではなく、配列の各要素を受け取る関数にすると、よりすっきりと記述することができます。

```
input_data = [1, 2, 3]

print(list(map(
    lambda x: x + 3 if x > 2 else x + 1,
    input_data,
)))
```